# TSQL - View with cross apply and pivot

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql

this is my base table:

```
docID |  rowNumber | Column1 |  Column2 | Column3
```

I use cross apply and pivot to transform the records in Column1 to actual columns and use the values in column2 and column3 as records for the new columns. In my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd4ab/1) you can see base and transformed select statement.

I have columns like Plant and Color which are numbered, e.g. Plant1, Plant2, Plant3, Color1, Color2 etc.

For each plant that exists in all plant columns I want to create a new row with a comma separated list of colors in one single column.

What I want to achieve is also in below screenshot:

[image: input-output]

This should become a view to use in Excel. How do I need to modify the view to get to the desired result?

Additional question: The Length-column is numeric. Is there any way to switch the decimal separator from within Excel as a user and apply it to this or all numeric column(s) so that it will be recognized by Excel as a number?
I used to have an old php web query where I would pass the separator from a dropdown cell in Excel as a parameter.

Thank you.

Comment: A bigger picture would be greatly helpful

Comment: right-click the image -> "show image" or something. It will get bigger :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, man the way your data is stored is a mess. I would recommend reading up on good data structures and fixing yours if you can. Here's a TSQL query that gets you the data in the correct format.

```
WITH CTE_no_nums
AS
(
SELECT  docID,
        CASE
            WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',column1) > 0
                THEN SUBSTRING(column1,0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',column1))
            ELSE column1
        END AS cols,
        COALESCE(column2,column3) AS vals
FROM miscValues
WHERE       column2 IS NOT NULL
        OR  column3 IS NOT NULL
),
CTE_Pivot
    AS
    (
    SELECT docID,partNumber,prio,[length],material
    FROM CTE_no_nums
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(vals) FOR cols IN (partNumber,prio,[length],material)
    ) pvt
)

SELECT  A.docId + ' # ' + B.vals AS [DocID # Plant],
        A.docID,
        A.partNumber,
        A.prio,
        B.vals AS Plant,
        A.partNumber + '#' + A.material + '#' + A.[length] AS Identification,
        A.[length],
        SUBSTRING(CA.colors,0,LEN(CA.colors)) colors --substring removes last comma
FROM CTE_Pivot A
INNER JOIN CTE_no_nums B
    ON      A.docID = B.docID
        AND B.cols = 'Plant'
CROSS APPLY (   SELECT vals + ',' 
                FROM CTE_no_nums C 
                WHERE   cols = 'Color' 
                    AND C.docID = A.docID 
                FOR XML PATH('') 
            ) CA(colors)
```

Results:

```
DocID # Plant    docID  partNumber prio Plant      Identification     length  colors
---------------- ------ ---------- ---- ---------- ------------------ ------- -------------------------
D0001 # PlantB   D0001  X001       1    PlantB     X001#MA123#10.87   10.87   white,black,blue
D0001 # PlantC   D0001  X001       1    PlantC     X001#MA123#10.87   10.87   white,black,blue
D0002 # PlantA   D0002  X002       2    PlantA     X002#MA456#16.43   16.43   black,yellow
D0002 # PlantC   D0002  X002       2    PlantC     X002#MA456#16.43   16.43   black,yellow
D0002 # PlantD   D0002  X002       2    PlantD     X002#MA456#16.43   16.43   black,yellow
```

Comment: really beautiful. Thank you very much Stephan! I know the data is a mess but unfortunately I have no influence on that.

Comment: How do I need to modify the substring function if Plant and Color 'columns' with two digits like Color12 are added?

Comment: I figured as much Tony. That's the usual. Someone makes a big mess and then others are stuck using it. As far as two digit numbers, sorry about that. I forgot a wildcard '%' in my PATINDEX(). Now, it should work for any amount of digits.